# python setuptools - creating custom directory

Tags: python, setuptools

The python app I am building requires the following structure to function properly:

- `/opt/mypackage/plugins` directory
- `/opt/mypackage/conf.json`

I would like to create a (source/wheels) package with setuptools that creates the structure and provides a default `conf.json` so that the user does not have to perform any manual steps to get started.

The only way I found for it is:

Override the cmdclass `install` in setup

```
setup(
    cmdclass={
        'install': CustomInstallCommand,
    },
)
```

In the `CustomInstallComman` class in `run` call the

```
setuptools.command.install.install.run()
```

method, see (http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#non-package-data-files)

The questions are:

1. Is it best practice to let `setup.py` handling those steps or should I deliver a separate build configuration and let user execute it?
2. Is there any better hook in `setuptools` to perform custom steps on setup?